# How to identify and flag a sub-string from a column of entries in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I'd like to add a column to my query that has a binary Yes/No, depending on whether a substring can be found anywhere in another column.

Example: I'd like to find TTY and have them labelled in the new column:

```
Name | ...... | Flag_Column

TestTTY123          Yes
Test-test           No
TTY111              Yes
11TTY11             Yes
Test-tube           No
Test-TTY            Yes
```

Sorry if the question is very simple, I've tried searching for a solution, but it seems that it's a bit more particular than the ones I've come across.

I've tried

```
case when INSTR(NAME,'TTY') = 1 THEN 'Yes'
else 'No' 
end Flag_Column
```

I was also considering using the *like* function, but it didn't seem like a good fit. Any suggestions pointing to an obvious solution I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost got the right solution.  INSTR won't always return 1 when it matches but rather a number corresponding to the location in the string it found the match.

Just change your query to:

```
case when INSTR(name,'TTY') > 0 THEN 'Yes'
else 'No' 
end Flag_Column
```

Comment: Excellent! I felt like I was close. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you also need to consider case insensitive search(to return `Yes` for values such as `tty`, `TTY`, `TtY` ..), then `REGEXP_LIKE()`

```
 select case when REGEXP_LIKE(name,'TTY','i') then 'Yes'
        else 'No' 
        end as Flag_Column
   from t
```

Or `REGEXP_INSTR()` might be used :

```
 select case when REGEXP_INSTR(name,'TTY',1,1,0,'i') > 0 then 'Yes'
        else 'No' 
        end as Flag_Column
   from t
```

Answer (score 1):

Even `instr` might be overcomplicating it, if the requirement is a simple pattern match. How about just:

```
case
    when name like '%TTY%' then 'Yes'
    else 'No' 
end as flag_column
```

Why didn't `like` seem like a good fit?